# CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing' . where i need to write code in webapi (service) or in client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, asp.net-web-api

i have one web api , which has basic authentication. that api code i cant change .can we add cors concept to retrieve data in client side applciation either in web.config or enabling CORS in client side application to resolve the issue of  Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://example.com/abc. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

code

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
                <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.city }}</td>
                               </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('https://example.com/abc', {
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'abc:abc', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }
    }).then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
});
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: the server serving the content needs to set the headers

Comment: you need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers in your service. not in the angular appication

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following two lines in your WebApiConfig

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("....", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

The `"..."` should contain the url of your web app.

For more info and alternatives, please have a look [here](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api).

Furthermore, there isn't any need for the client to set the following:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
```

Comment: but i dont have access to modify code of web api service. cant we change the code and apply cors in client side.

Comment: no, CORS is a security measure to protect clients (browsers), being able to "override" a security measure on the client side would mean that there's no security measure at all.

Answer (score 0):

If the web server is IIS. You can edit the web.confg.

```
<system.webServer>
 <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Asp.NET WEBAPI you can resolve the issue ..without set it in client ..but directly in the server...try to put in your StartUp.cs

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            ConfigureAuth(app);

        }
```

And in your WebConfig in the section  somthing like:

```
<handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="WebDAV"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: cant we add settings in client side to  resolve cors header missing issue

Comment: no .. on the client you need to use Jsonp ..but it's really unfriendly .. if you have control on your back end..use this solution

Comment: jsonp code on server side?? .. no understand sorry ..and no i don't know other options...

Comment: can we use jsonp in client application only without writing jsonp code in server side(api).is there any other option ? i have access on client application, no control of api(service)

Comment: so this is the case to use jsonp (if you use it you don't have to write anything on server side)

Comment: code on server side means - coding of webapi (service) which i cant modify the code of webapi

Comment: i understand it .. and i say to you ..if you use jsonp ..you don't have to write nothing on back end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131886/discussion-between-swapna-and-federico-scamuzzi).

Comment: `if you use jsonp ..you don't have to write nothing on back end` - except the code to handle jsonp responses of course